# Hide device information pop-up on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

In my Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300, rooted, SuperUser installed), I have a static pop-up that shows some information about my device hardware and doesn't hide. The pop-up has a background color and yellow text. It has some information like:

```
PDA:blah
Phone:blah
CSC:blah
and more...
```

[image]

How can I hide the pop-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your device is in *Factory Mode*. To exit from it manually:

1. Open file manager that can access root folder (e.g. [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer), [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop))
2. Go to `/efs/FactoryApp/`
3. Open `factorymode` file as text file. Change the content to `ON` and save the file
4. Open `keystr` file as text file. Change the content to `ON` and save the file
5. Reboot the device

---

Alternatively:

1. Install [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)
2. Type `su`
3. Type (or copy-paste)

   ```
   rm /efs/FactoryApp/keystr
   rm /efs/FactoryApp/factorymode
   echo -n ON >> /efs/FactoryApp/keystr
   echo -n ON >> /efs/FactoryApp/factorymode
   chown 1000.1000 /efs/FactoryApp/keystr
   chown 1000.1000 /efs/FactoryApp/factorymode
   chmod 0744 /efs/FactoryApp/keystr
   chmod 0744 /efs/FactoryApp/factorymode
   reboot
   ```

---

You can also exit factory mode and remove the annoying message without root, but it won't fix it:

1. Go to **Settings > Application manager > All**
2. Search *Factory Test* and "Clear data", "Clear cache"

---

Reference: [ZiDroid - How to Exit Factory Mode for Samsung Galaxy Devices](http://zidroid.com/how-to-exit-factory-mode-for-samsung-galaxy-devices/)